# How to remove bulb from this Harden faucet to replace cartridge

Tags: faucet

[image: faucet bulb]My widespread Harden faucet has set screw that removes the handle but the white base bulb will not come off. I can turn the bulb but there is a metal rim which extends inside the bulb and prevents it from being pulled up. When I turn the bulb, the metal above the bulb does not turn so somehow I need to get that out.  Faucet is leaking and I need to replace the cartridge.

Comment: Try to grasp the chrome collar with a pair of vice grips, (carefully so you don't scratch the surface) and urn it counterclockwise. It should come off.

Comment: Thank you Jack!! I was able to get it off with vice grips although I didn't manage the "don't scratch it part"- kind of hard to grasp it...  Anyway, on to the  next part, replacing the cartridge. I've found lots of videos on that so I think I can do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to grasp the chrome collar with a pair of vice grips, (carefully so you don't scratch the surface) and urn it counterclockwise. It should come off.